# Can this regular expression be simplified?

Tags: regex

I have this regex:

```
^(\(\d{3}\)[ ]?\d{3}-\d{4})|(\d{3}\.\d{3}\.\d{4})|(\d{3}\-\d{3}\-\d{4})|[0-9]{10}$
```

I need **only** these phone number formats to match:

- (555) 555-5555
- (555)555-5555
- 555-555-5555
- 555.555.5555
- 5555555555

**Is there any way to simplify my current regular expression?**

Comment: If you're wanting **strict** then leave it as is.

Comment: @hwnd I believe you are right. I'm still new to regex, so I wanted to verify with some SO gurus before throwing it in. Thanks.

Comment: I hope you're not trying to validate a phone number field. The right way to handle phone numbers is to strip non-digit characters and then evaluate the numeric series.

Comment: @zzzzBov This is for a RESTful API. I'm validating an element in a request body.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

RegexBuddy Shows:

```
\(?\b[0-9]{3}\)?[-. ]?[0-9]{3}[-. ]?[0-9]{4}\b
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but certain matches get by that should not. I need a strict match to only the formats mentioned above. I cannot mix a "." with a "-".

Answer (score 2):

Personally, I wouldn't bother validating the user's formatting. Whatever you come up with is likely going to fail in some scenarios. I think it's much better to accept a looser input and try your best to correct.

Honestly, who cares about `()`, `-`, and `.` when all you need is the 10 digits? You can easily add the formatting on the backend.

Instead, I'd do something like this

```
// ugly user input, but still valid
var userInput = "(500) 423.2345";

// remove all non-digits
var phone = userInput.replace(/\D/g, '');
//=> "5004232345"

// verify that 10 digits are present
if (phone.length !== 10) {
  alert("invalid phone number");
}
```

Then you can store the number in your any format you want

```
// example
[
  "(",
  phone.substr(0,3),
  ")",
  phone.substr(3,3),
  "-",
  phone.substr(6,4)
].join(" ")

// "( 500 ) 423 - 2345"
```

Comment: [Now you have two problems](http://blog.codinghorror.com/regular-expressions-now-you-have-two-problems/).

Answer (score 0):

You can simplify a little and avoid several alternatives if you use a capture group to catch the delimiter and a backreference `\1` to reuse it:

```
^(?:\(\d{3}\) ?\d{3}-\d{4}|\d{3}([.-]?)\d{3}\1\d{4})$
```